# Long running task in Cloud Run with CPU always allocated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, background-process, google-cloud-run

I know that since Oct-21 Cloud Run supports background jobs.

Anyone knows what happens with long-running background jobs in the following scenario?

- CPU always allocated is set to true
- min. number of instances is set to 1
- there are multiple instances at the same time due to higher load and each of them is coincidentally running a background job

Are all of those background jobs guaranteed to finish OR just the one running on that "always on" instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances created above minimum instances are subject to termination.

> Note that even if CPU is always allocated, Cloud Run autoscaling is
> still in effect, and may terminate container instances if they aren't
> needed to handle incoming traffic. An instance will never stay idle
> for more than 15 minutes after processing a request **unless it is kept
> active using minimum instances**.
>
> Combining CPU always allocated with a number of minimum instances
> results in a number of container instances up and running with full
> access to CPU resources, enabling background processing use cases like
> pulling Pub/Sub messages.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation